# JAX-RS Custom JSON representation of primitive Resource return type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Suppose we have a service with the following contract:

```
public interface CategoryService {

    public int createNew(String languageCode, String name, String descriptionMarkdown, Integer parentCategoryID, String createdByUserName) throws ServiceException;

};
```

How do I map the `int` return type to produce a JSON value like the following?

PS: I know that the `createNew` method will have to be an HTTP POST request (annotation `@POST`). Assumes annotations are there. I just need the response representation.

```
{"id": 1}
```

Comment: Is having return type `int` a requirement?

Comment: For now, yes as it is an interface used in EJB 3.x. The `CategoryResource` class is a JAX-RS class that implements this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a good idea. Would be much better if you'll create new JAX-RS resource and designated entity-class to response with.
 Still, if you want to mix marshalling with model, you could write your own MessageBodyWriter. For example:

```
@Produces("application/json")
public class IntWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        boolean intAsID = false;
        for (Annotation a : annotations) {
            if (a.annotationType().getCanonicalName().equals("com.blabla.IntAsID")) {
                intAsID = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return intAsID && (type == Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Integer integer, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Integer integer, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        JsonGenerator generator = Json.createGenerator(entityStream);
        generator.writeStartObject()
                .write("id", integer)
                .writeEnd()
                .flush();
    }
}
```

Several keypoints here.
 1.

Don't forget to register this writer in your configuration.

```
public class ServerConfig extends Application {

    private static final Set<Class<?>> classes
            = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        //register your resources
        classes.add(Test.class);
        //register message body writer
        classes.add(IntWriter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

}
```

2.

If you don't want to use use this writer for every resource returning int. Create some special annotation for your resource (for example IntAsID).

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IntAsID {}
```

Don't forget to set correct retention policy. And check presence of this annotation in `isWriteable` method. Like I did in my example.
And yes, add this annotation to your resource:

```
public interface CategoryService {

    @IntAsID
    public int createNew(String languageCode, String name, String descriptionMarkdown, Integer parentCategoryID, String createdByUserName) throws ServiceException;

};
```

3.

Use `@Produces` annotation. That will help your JAX-RS provider to don't check this writer in cases then Resource should produce not JSON, but something else.

4.

Don't care about `getSize()` method. Its result is ignored now (at least in Jersey).

5.

Don't close `entityStream` in `writeTo` method.

Comment: JBoss Wildfly 8.2.0-Final doesn't use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation. It uses RESTEasy as JAX-RS implementation. I forgot to state that the project relies purely on JAX-RS specification and not 3rd party specific as it'll run on different containers.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi as far as I remember, MessageBodyWriter is a part of JAX-RS, not Jersey-specific.

Comment: Not that, `ResourceConfig` is Jersey specific.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi oh, sure. I'll rewrite it later, when will be nearby PC. If in urge, you could inherit from Application (from whose ResourceConfig inherits): it's part of JAX-RS and works the same way.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi ok, I rewrote it. Now it should be pure JAX-RS.

Comment: Thanks. I've already accepted your answer. It's a good answer and because of this, I will decouple my services entirely and create an independent Restful service that won't be coupled with the service about (as EJB uses it).

Comment: For point 4, the Javadoc for `MessageBodyWriter` states: `As of JAX-RS 2.0, the method has been deprecated and the value returned by the method is ignored by a JAX-RS runtime. All MessageBodyWriter implementations are advised to return -1 from the method. Responsibility to compute the actual Content-Length header value has been delegated to JAX-RS runtime.`.